# angularjs - refactor XMLHttpRequest to $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

I want the following code

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("PUT", dbServer + "/configItemAdd");
    request.send(new FormData(form));
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {   window.location.reload(); }
};
```

to look like this

```
     const fd = new FormData(form);
     $http({
         method: 'PUT',
         url: dbServer + "/configItemAdd",
         data: fd
     }).then(function (resp){
         window.location.reload();
     });
```

the problem is I get two error messages:
with just labels and no file input I get 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0

and with file input I get 
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

the XMLHttpRequest code is working with and without input files.
Please help :S

Comment: you need to set headers as `Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an extra header i.e. `{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}` to your request

```
const fd = new FormData(form);
 $http({
     method: 'PUT',
     url: dbServer + "/configItemAdd",
     Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data'
     data: fd
 }).then(function (resp){
     window.location.reload();
 });
```